Why does Error handling gets Result<_, _>?
I have the following function in Rust. It converts all Torrent files to Magnet links. For some files it throws an Error. I wan't to skip those files
use rs_torrent_magnet;

pub fn build_cache(paths: Vec<PathBuf>, magnets: String, names: String){
    for path in paths{
        println!("Reading file: {:?}", path);
        let magnet = match rs_torrent_magnet::magnet_from_torrent_file(path) {
            Ok(magnet) => magnet,
            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("Error reading magnet from torrent file: {:?}", e);
                return;
            }
        };
    }
}

But I get the following compiler error:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/scraper.rs:33:13
   |
32 |         let magnet = match rs_torrent_magnet::magnet_from_torrent_file(path) {
   |                            ------------------------------------------------- this expression has type `std::string::String`
33 |             Ok(magnet) => magnet,
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ expected `String`, found `Result<_, _>`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::string::String`
                found enum `Result<_, _>`


Why does it return Result<_, _> instead of String?

You're trying to treat the result of magnet_from_torrent_file as a Result, but it's not -- it's a String. This function may have a different way to signal errors, such as by panicking, but it's not documented so there isn't much to go on without digging into the internals.

(Luckily, the whole package is about 40 lines of logic to dig into, and yeah, it just panics on every error).

Ok. Thank you for your answer :). I thought treating as a result was a simple way to catch errors.

@Konrad Normally you'd be correct, but for that to work, the function you call has to return a Result. That this library doesn't do that is just bad practice, and you should consider switching to a different library (or in this case even writing your own code that does the same thing, but with proper error handling).

It indeed panics. Seeing this kind of usage of unwrap in production code is a red flag. I suggest OP looks for another library.
